# How do I get the count of SMS messages per contact into a textview?

Tags: android, count, sms, contacts, message

I have a **listview** that displays the contacts on my device. What I'm trying to do is display the number of text messages my device has received from each contact into a textview within my listview. I have only been able to display the **total** number of text messages within my inbox from this code:

```
        // gets total count of messages in inbox
        String folder = "content://sms/inbox";
        Uri mSmsQueryUri = Uri.parse(folder);
        String columns[] = new String[] {"person", "address", "body", "date","status"}; 
        String sortOrder = "date ASC"; 
        Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(mSmsQueryUri, columns, null, null, sortOrder);

        textview.setText(c.getCount());
```

The problem with the above code is that for every row in my listview, this only shows the total. How can I split the total number between to it's corresponding contact?

The end result is like this if I had **100 messages in my inbox**:
**Contacts:**

Foo Manchuu: 25

Bar Bee: 15

Sna Fuu: 10

John Doe: 50

Answer (score 3):

```
Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/");

Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(c);
    String[] count = new String[c.getCount()];
    String[] snippet = new String[c.getCount()];
    String[] thread_id = new String[c.getCount()];

    c.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        count[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("msg_count"))
                .toString();
        thread_id[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("thread_id"))
                .toString();
        snippet[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"))
                .toString();
        Log.v("count", count[i]);
        Log.v("thread", thread_id[i]);
        Log.v("snippet", snippet[i]);
        c.moveToNext();
    }
```

See log and problem solved. Dont repost the same question : [How do I display the count of text messages received from a contact?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573178/how-do-i-display-the-count-of-text-messages-received-from-a-contact)

Comment: your solution is incomplete. What is returning?

Comment: count is number of each sender's message. Thread-id is the order in normal inbox. Snippet is the last message in conversation.

Comment: this still doesn't show me how to use it for my textview in my listview

Comment: Create custom adapter with your own model . There's no way u can directly pass to normal simplecursor adapter. Here is the original android model that u can refer [Conversation](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/data/Conversation.java) and layout for row item [ConversationListItem] (https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/ui/ConversationListItem.java)

Answer (score 1):

I would perhaps add `count(person) AS cnt` to the `columns` String array and then I would add `person` as the `groupBy` argument to the `query` method.

**EDIT:**

And as pointed out by *Jens*, the `GROUP BY` paradigm isn't supported by the messaging ContentProvider.

What you could do is to create an in-memory database of your own at application startup (http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) and copy-paste (query-insert) messages of interest from the system messaging database into your in-memory database. (**NOTE!** That this might fall out wrong if you are low on memory and have a tremendous amount of messages you're interested in). Since you'd be God in the in-memory database you could query it as you see fit with any exotic SQL querys you'd like...

Comment: He's calling the messaging content provider, groupBy:s and other nice/fancy stuff isn't really supported (although, you can still pull a lot of weird shit in the selection & selection arguments).