# select distinct value in android query (Android L)

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-5.0-lollipop

How do I call ContentResolver.query method in Android L (API 20) with distinct?
Ref- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html

This API does not have bool distinct parameter overloaded query method as earlier APIs did.

I am trying to query on "content://sms/inbox" and I want only distinct messages (only latest one in each message thread) to show in the main messages listview.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10593563/1050058). Snippet is the last message in each conversation.

Comment: Thanks. That will work for the purpose here but I would still like to know the way to select distinct in L