# Count sent sms messages for a single thread

Tags: android, sms

I'm looking for the count of sent sms messages in a particular thread (say, with id 15). I found this [How do I get the count of SMS messages per contact into a textview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580303/how-do-i-get-the-count-of-sms-messages-per-contact-into-a-textview) <-- but it doesn't solve my issue, as it counts both sent and received sms messages. Is it possible to count only sent messages? I think I could query "content://sms/sent" and walk through each SMS, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query `Sms.Conversations` with your thread ID, and a selection that restricts the `TYPE` column to `MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT`. Since you just want the count, we can do a `SELECT COUNT()` query, so there's no resources wasted building a `Cursor` with unused values. For example:

```
private int getThreadSentCount(String threadId) {
    final Uri uri = Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI
                    .buildUpon()
                    .appendEncodedPath(threadId)
                    .build();
    final String[] projection = {"COUNT(1)"};
    final String selection = Sms.TYPE + "=" + Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT;

    int count = -1;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                                            projection,
                                            selection,
                                            null,
                                            null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            count = cursor.getInt(0);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

The `Sms` class used above is in the `android.provider.Telephony` class.

```
import android.provider.Telephony.Sms;
```

For reference, `Sms.Conversations.CONTENT_URI` is equivalent to `Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations")`, `Sms.TYPE` is `"type"`, and `Sms.MESSAGE_TYPE_SENT` is `2`.